# swift deinit method not working when UIView is removed from memory

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, deinit

In `Swift` ARC is calling `deinit` when any `UIViewController` is removing from memory , but it's not getting called if any `UIView` is removed from memory.

for example

**In case of `UIViewController` Class `deinit` is working great**

```
class MusicPlayerUIViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
    {
    deinit
        {
            APP_DELEGATE.RemovePlayerContents()
        }
    }
```

**but in case of `UIView` Class `deinit` not working**

```
class MusicPlayerView: UIView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
deinit
    {
        APP_DELEGATE.RemovePlayerContents()
    }
}
```

any idea .

Comment: Are you sure that you release this view?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this - why deinit method on UIView is not being called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parent ViewController can hold you UIView. You have to set to nil a property, that stored you `UIView` in parent `UIViewController` for release uiview.

Or override `removeFromSuperview()` and place your deinit code in it.